# angular inner scope override out scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am pretty new to angular an try to figure out how scope works.

I define 2 controllers OuterCtrl and InnerCtrl, InnerCtrl is nested into OuterCtrl.
they both define the same variable user.age in scope.

As I understand, InnerCtrl and OuterCtrl have different scope, so they should to different value when I print it out with expression

```
{{user.age}}
```

But it seems like the inner scope override the outer scope as the result shows. [test code](http://plnkr.co/edit/BKKlP7?p=preview)

#### Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner scope inherits `user` from the outer scope. The inner controller overrides the `age` property of that object.

If you had `$scope.user={};` in your inner controller as well, then it would have its own `user` object and you would see different values.

Comment: I know that this is an old answer, but @zeroflagL just solved my problem after 2 solid days of pouring over code.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because all child `scopes` will inherit their parent `scopes`.

An example from the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

> When Angular evaluates {{name}}, it first looks at the scope associated with the given element for the name property. If no such property is found, it searches the parent scope and so on until the root scope is reached. In JavaScript this behavior is known as prototypical inheritance, and child scopes prototypically inherit from their parents.

Comment: but the problem here is the opposite, it is the child scope override parent scope, not inherit